Spring data jpa error "Unknown column in 'where clause'"
These are my Entity classes.
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class IdEntity {
  @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  protected Long id;

  @Version
  protected Long version;
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class UidEntity {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    protected Long id;

    protected String uid;
}

@Entity
public class Third extends UidEntity {
}

@Entity
public class Second extends IdEntity {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "third_id", nullable = false,
        foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_second_third_id"))
    private Third third;
}

An abstract class and one of the classes based on that
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type_")
public abstract class First extends IdEntity {
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "second_id", nullable = false,
        foreignKey = @ForeignKey(name = "fk_first_second_id"))
    private Second second;
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("string")
public class StringFirstClass extends FirstClass {
    @Column(name = "v_string")
    private String value;
}

Note: Some code below are in Scala, but it is readable.
I have a FirstClassRepository which implements an IdRepository.
IdRepository[T <: IdEntity,Id <: java.io.Serializable] extends
  PagingAndSortingRepository[T, Id] with ListCrudRepository[T, Id] with
  JpaSpecificationExecutor[T] {
}

I created a Specification[FirstClass] as below.
(root:Root[Attribute], _:CriteriaQuery[_], builder:CriteriaBuilder) => {
   return builder.equal(root.get("second").get("third").get("uid"), "uuid1234")
}

If I call, firstClassRepository.delete(spec), it generates a wrong SQL statement and throws error.

org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: JDBC
exception executing SQL [delete from first_class where exists(select 1
from second_class s1_0 where s1_0.id=first_class.second_id and
t1_0.uid=?)] [Unknown column 't1_0.uid' in 'where clause'] [n/a]; SQL
[n/a]

Please help in resolving this issue.
Library versions from mvn dependency:tree:

org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:3.2.9
jakarta.persistence:jakarta.persistence-api:jar:3.1.0
org.hibernate.orm:hibernate-core:jar:6.4.10.Final
org.springframework:spring-jdbc:jar:6.1.12


In the model you've shown, Second doesn't have a reference or 'first' attribute, so did you maybe mean to use 'third' in root.get("second").get("first")? I don't know spring specifications well enough, but JPA criteria exists requires a subquery, and this look like it wasn't well formed. You might make simple test cases with a select and exists query to see if you are hitting a bug

@Chris It was a typo. I have updated the question. Thank you for pointing this out. It seems I should have given real world names for the Entities rather than First, second and Third.
I don't understand your suggestion "JPA criteria exists requires a subquery". Here, it is not checking if the data exists. It is trying to delete the data. Another thing, I need to point out is this error start happening when we upgraded Spring Boot from 3.1.6 to 3.2.9

Exists clauses is how you have to filter delete statements - using a subquery allows executing filtering with joins. You can write the same select query being used for the delete statement and it might help find where in the code there might be an issue, but looks like a bug to me
